# Is it possible to embed a cdf file into a GitHub Page

Tags: cdfplayer

At the bottom of my [page](http://hypergroups.github.io/), I've added a piece of CDF js code, but it doesn't evoke the *Wolfram CDF Player* or *Mathematica*, so I can't play with it.

And I wonder whether it's possible, since I know GitHub pages are some static pages.

[image]

---

## Update

Today I found the cdf in my homepage could be aroused by CDF palyer. ???

Comment: In addition to the embedding code, one usually needs to ensure the webserver sends the right MIME type. And afaik, github does not allow this, [see](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15951012/can-mime-types-of-github-pages-files-be-configured)

Comment: It's always so funny for a european like me to look on an asian website. I feel like I'm in the middle of a color-storm. I can only guess how boring web-pages like stackexchange must be for you with their very *clear and simple* design.

Comment: @halirutan Please No Prejudice! PLEASE! You're looking at the tail of a `NormalDistribution`! We asian *can* have less colorful [site](http://silvia-hi.me)... (ok it's colorful as well, but hey they're from [*your* code-prettify](https://github.com/halirutan/Mathematica-Source-Highlighting) :P )

Comment: @caya I've installed CDF player, it seems I can use CDF in my github page now?

Comment: Yes, it's possible, see here is one example https://chenminqi.github.io/%E9%BB%91%E7%99%BD%E6%A3%8B/

Comment: I'm having issues with the link http://chenminqi.github.io/%E9%BB%91%E7%99%BD%E6%A3%8B/ but I believe you that it works.  Plz post an answer if it works.

Answer (score 1):

The answer appears no because github doesn't support the proper mimetype for cdf of documents.

[Here](https://github.com/jshttp/mime-db/blob/master/db.json) is the actually list but although cdf is listed I don't believe it is referring to Mathematica's cdf.

[Mimetypes are explained here.](https://help.github.com/articles/mime-types-on-github-pages/)

Comment: William could you expand your answer by adding e.g. some supporting links etc?

Comment: It's possible, see@ one example https://chenminqi.github.io/%E9%BB%91%E7%99%BD%E6%A3%8B/